# Fit a generalized linear model (glm) with a categorical variable of month using the function monthglm() in R

Tags: r, function, regression, glm

**Problem**

I have a data frame (see below) and I want to fit a general linear model (glm) with a categorical variable of the month using the function monthglm() based on the covariates of season and year.

After I run the following function, which was written by [Barnett, A.G., Dobson, A.J. (2010) Analysing Seasonal Health Data. Springer.](https://rdrr.io/cran/season/man/monthglm.html) (see below), I keep on getting this error message.

If anyone can help, I would be deeply appreciative.

**Load packages**

```
library(season)
library(MASS) # for mvrnorm
library(survival) # for coxph
library(ggplot2)
```

**Function:**

```
monthglm<-function(formula,data,family=gaussian(),refmonth=1,
                   monthvar='month',offsetmonth=FALSE,offsetpop=NULL){
  ## checks
  if (refmonth<1|refmonth>12){stop("Reference month must be between 1 and 12")}
  ## original call with defaults (see amer package)
  ans <- as.list(match.call())
  frmls <- formals(deparse(ans[[1]]))
  add <- which(!(names(frmls) %in% names(ans)))
  call<-as.call(c(ans, frmls[add]))
  
  monthvar=with(data,get(monthvar))
  cmonthvar=class(monthvar)
  ## If month is a character, create the numbers
  if(cmonthvar%in%c('factor','character')){
    if(cmonthvar=='character'){
      if(max(nchar(monthvar))==3){mlevels=substr(month.name,1,3)}else{mlevels=month.name}
      monthvar=factor(monthvar,levels=mlevels)
    }
    months=as.numeric(monthvar)
    data$month=months # add to data for flagleap
    months=as.factor(months)
    levels(months)[months]<-month.abb[months]
    months<-relevel(months.u,ref=month.abb[refmonth]) # set reference month
  }
  ## Transform month numbers to names
  if(cmonthvar%in%c('integer','numeric')){
    months.u<-as.factor(monthvar)  
    nums<-as.numeric(nochars(levels(months.u))) # Month numbers
    levels(months.u)[nums]<-month.abb[nums]
    months<-relevel(months.u,ref=month.abb[refmonth]) # set reference month
  }
  ## prepare data/formula
  parts<-paste(formula)
  f<-as.formula(paste(parts[2],parts[1],parts[3:length(formula)],'+months'))
  dep<-parts[2] # dependent variable
  days<-flagleap(data=data,report=FALSE,matchin=T) # get the number of days in each month
  l<-nrow(data)
  if(is.null(offsetpop)==FALSE){poff=with(data,eval(offsetpop))} else{poff=rep(1,l)} # 
  if(offsetmonth==TRUE){moff=days$ndaysmonth/(365.25/12)} else{moff=rep(1,l)} # days per month divided by average month length
  ###  data$off<-log(poff*moff)
  off<-log(poff*moff)  # 
  fit<-glm(formula=f,data=data,family=family,offset=off)
  ## return
  toret<-list()
  toret$call<-call
  toret$glm<-fit
  toret$fitted.values<-fitted(fit)
  toret$residuals<-residuals(fit)
  class(toret)<-'monthglm'
  return(toret)
}

#The levels of a factor must match the observed values. 
#If you want to change how those values print out, you need to change the labels.
```

**Error message**

```
model<-monthglm(formula=Frequency_Blue~Year+Monsoon_Season, family=gaussian,
+                       offsetmonth=TRUE, refmonth=1, data=Final_New_Blue)
Error in nochars(levels(months.u)) : could not find function "nochars"
```

**Dataframe**

```
   structure(list(Year = c(2015L, 2016L, 2017L, 2015L, 2016L, 2017L, 
2015L, 2016L, 2017L, 2015L, 2016L, 2017L, 2015L, 2016L, 2017L, 
2015L, 2016L, 2017L, 2015L, 2016L, 2017L, 2015L, 2016L, 2017L, 
2015L, 2016L, 2017L, 2015L, 2016L, 2017L, 2015L, 2016L, 2017L, 
2015L, 2016L, 2017L), Month = structure(c(5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 3L, 
3L, 3L), .Label = c("April", "August", "December", "Feb", "Jan", 
"July", "June", "Mar", "May", "November", "October", "September"
), class = "factor"), Frequency_Blue_Whales_Year_Month = c(76L, 
78L, 66L, 28L, 54L, 37L, 39L, 31L, 88L, 46L, 23L, 54L, 5L, 8L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 7L, 22L, 6L, 44L, 10L, 30L, 35L, 88L, 
41L, 35L, 4L, 30L, 43L, 65L, 43L, 90L), Season = structure(c(4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
5L, 5L, 5L), .Label = c("Autumn", "Spring", "Summer", "winter", 
"Winter"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-36L))
```

**Arguments**

[image]

Comment: I don't get the same error from your example. I get an error from the fact that your code does not specify `monthvar`, and the function searches for default val of `month`. If I add that argument, I get a different error about  missing value `months.u`

Comment: The `nochars` function is internal to the `season` package, so it is surprising that you are getting that error. Are you sure you loaded the package? Are you manually entering the function code just for this post or is that how you're running the code?

Comment: I tried to install season again: This is the error message: library(season)
Loading required package: ggplot2
Loading required package: MASS
Loading required package: survival

Attaching package: ‘season’

The following object is masked _by_ ‘.GlobalEnv’:

    monthglm

Warning message:
package ‘season’ was built under R version 4.0.2

Comment: Whale_model<-monthglm(formula=Frequency_Blue~Year+Monsoon_Season, family=gaussian,
+                       offsetmonth=TRUE, monthvar='Month', refmonth=1, data=Final_New_Blue)
Error in relevel(months.u, ref = month.abb[refmonth]) : 
  object 'months.u' not found

Comment: If I add monthvar = 'Month' to the model, this is the error message above. Do you know what the problem is here? I'm relatively new to R

Comment: If I use this version of the model: Whale_model<-monthglm(formula=Frequency_Blue~Year+Monsoon_Season, family=gaussian(),
+                       offsetmonth=TRUE, monthvar='January', refmonth=1, data=Final_New_Blue)
Error in vector(length = ndays, mode = "numeric") : 
  vector size cannot be NA/NaN
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In min(data$year) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
2: In max(data$year) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf

Comment: I get this error message

Comment: I believe the `months.u` issue is a typo in the code. One of the `months.u` vairables is not defined in a branch of the `if` statement. If you change the FIRST instance of the following code to this: `months<-relevel(months,ref=month.abb[refmonth])` it took care of the `months.u` issue. Your new error I'll take a stab at but cannot figure out atm

Comment: I am sorry to ask another question astrofunkswag. I am now using the function monthmean() in the Season package and I am experiencing some difficulties. Would it be possible to please ask your advice? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63486896/how-to-calculate-the-average-monthly-mean-using-the-function-monthmean-in-the?noredirect=1#comment112265937_63486896

Comment: Don't feel too bad, but comment sections should be constrained to answering a question. See my advice in my answer that you are relying on a package with only one contributor, so you're likely to keep running into bugs. Calculating a monthly average is something you could learn to do with base R code, and not have to rely on a package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to get the model to run with the following simple change to the code and your function call. I named it `monthglm2` to distinguish it from the package function. With calling your data `df`:

```
library(season)
library(MASS) # for mvrnorm
library(survival) # for coxph
library(ggplot2)


monthglm2<-function(formula,data,family=gaussian(),refmonth=1,
                   monthvar='month',offsetmonth=FALSE,offsetpop=NULL){
  ## checks
  if (refmonth<1|refmonth>12){stop("Reference month must be between 1 and 12")}
  ## original call with defaults (see amer package)
  ans <- as.list(match.call())
  frmls <- formals(deparse(ans[[1]]))
  add <- which(!(names(frmls) %in% names(ans)))
  call<-as.call(c(ans, frmls[add]))

  monthvar=with(data,get(monthvar))
  cmonthvar=class(monthvar)
  ## If month is a character, create the numbers
  if(cmonthvar%in%c('factor','character')){
    if(cmonthvar=='character'){
      if(max(nchar(monthvar))==3){mlevels=substr(month.name,1,3)}else{mlevels=month.name}
      monthvar=factor(monthvar,levels=mlevels)
    }
    months=as.numeric(monthvar)
    data$month=months # add to data for flagleap
    months=as.factor(months)
    levels(months)[months]<-month.abb[months]
    months<-relevel(months,ref=month.abb[refmonth]) # set reference month ### TYPO HERE, changed from months.u
  }
  ## Transform month numbers to names
  if(cmonthvar%in%c('integer','numeric')){
    months.u<-as.factor(monthvar)
    nums<-as.numeric(nochars(levels(months.u))) # Month numbers
    levels(months.u)[nums]<-month.abb[nums]
    months<-relevel(months.u,ref=month.abb[refmonth]) # set reference month
  }
  ## prepare data/formula
  parts<-paste(formula)
  f<-as.formula(paste(parts[2],parts[1],parts[3:length(formula)],'+months'))
  dep<-parts[2] # dependent variable
  days<-flagleap(data=data,report=FALSE,matchin=T) # get the number of days in each month
  l<-nrow(data)
  if(is.null(offsetpop)==FALSE){poff=with(data,eval(offsetpop))} else{poff=rep(1,l)} #
  if(offsetmonth==TRUE){moff=days$ndaysmonth/(365.25/12)} else{moff=rep(1,l)} # days per month divided by average month length
  ###  data$off<-log(poff*moff)
  off<-log(poff*moff)  #
  fit<-glm(formula=f,data=data,family=family,offset=off)
  ## return
  toret<-list()
  toret$call<-call
  toret$glm<-fit
  toret$fitted.values<-fitted(fit)
  toret$residuals<-residuals(fit)
  class(toret)<-'monthglm'
  return(toret)
}


df$year <- df$Year
monthglm2(formula=Frequency_Blue_Whales_Year_Month~Year+Season, family=gaussian(),  offsetmonth=TRUE, monthvar='Month', refmonth=1, data=df)
```

There was the additional issue in the function where I had to rename a column to `year`. If you look at the [github](https://github.com/agbarnett/season/graphs/contributors) for this package there is only one contributor and no issues raised. There are pros and cons to using packages such as this: they might have novel approaches that are useful, but bugs are not quickly identified and addressed. If you continue forward with seasonal analysis I'd recommend trying to learn the how to include seasonal modeling in `glm` directly

Comment: Thank you! I really do appreciate your help. Have a great day :)