# How to calculate the average monthly mean using the function monthmean() in the season pacakge in R

Tags: r, dplyr, time-series, average, mean

**Problem:**

I have a data frame called **FID** (see below) and I want to produce a table showing the average monthly mean of FID for all three years (2015-2017)

After I run the function, which was written by [Adrian Barnett](http://https:/https://rdrr.io/cran/season/man/monthmean.html), I am experiencing this error message:

```
Error in monthmean(data = New_Blue_Edited_Final, resp = New_Blue_Edited_Final$FID,  : 
  data set must contain a variable with the numeric month called 'month'
```

If anyone can help, I would be deeply appreciative.

```
#Load package
library(season)

#R code for the monthmean()function

   monthmean<-function(data,resp,offsetpop=NULL,adjmonth=FALSE){
  # checks
  if (is.null(data)==TRUE){stop("must have an input data set (data)")}
  if (is.null(resp)==TRUE){stop("must have an input variable (resp)")}
  nnn<-names(data)
  if (any(nnn=='year')==FALSE){stop("data set must contain a variable with the 4 digit year called 'year'")}
  if (any(nnn=='month')==FALSE){stop("data set must contain a variable with the numeric month called 'month'")}
  # calculations
  days<-flagleap(data) # get the number of days in each month
  mean<-vector(length=12,mode='numeric')
  if (adjmonth=='thirty') adjf=30  
  if (adjmonth=='average') adjf=365.25/12
  if (is.null(offsetpop)==TRUE) adjp=1 else adjp=with(data,eval(offsetpop)) # population adjustment
  xxxx=subset(data,select=resp)[,1] # instead of with
  for (i in 1:12){
    if (adjmonth!=FALSE) mean[i]<-mean(xxxx[data$month==i]*(adjf/days$ndaysmonth[i])/adjp)
    else mean[i]<-mean(xxxx[data$month==i]/adjp) # no monthly adjustment
  }
  # return
  toret<-list()
  toret$mean<-as.vector(mean)
  class(toret)<-'Monthmean'
  return(toret)
}

 #Model

 FID$year <- FID$Year

 mean_FID<-monthmean(data=FID,
                     resp=FID$FID,
                     adjmonth = "thirty")
```

**Error Message**

```
Error in monthmean(data = New_Blue_Edited_Final, resp = New_Blue_Edited_Final$FID,  : 
  data set must contain a variable with the numeric month called 'month'
```

**Data frame called 'FID'**

```
structure(list(FID = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 
11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 
24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 
37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 
50L, 51L, 52L, 53L, 54L, 55L, 56L, 57L, 58L, 59L, 60L, 61L, 62L, 
63L, 64L, 65L, 66L, 67L, 68L, 69L, 70L, 71L, 72L, 73L, 74L, 75L, 
76L, 77L, 78L, 79L, 80L, 81L, 82L, 83L, 84L, 85L, 86L, 87L, 88L, 
89L, 90L, 91L, 92L, 93L, 94L, 95L, 96L, 97L, 98L, 99L, 100L, 
101L, 102L, 103L, 104L, 105L, 106L, 107L, 108L, 109L, 110L, 111L, 
112L, 113L, 114L, 115L, 116L, 117L, 118L, 119L, 120L, 121L, 122L, 
123L, 124L, 125L, 126L, 127L, 128L, 129L, 130L, 131L, 132L, 133L, 
134L, 135L, 136L, 137L, 138L, 139L, 140L, 141L, 142L, 144L, 145L, 
146L, 147L, 148L, 149L, 150L, 151L, 152L, 153L, 154L, 155L, 156L, 
157L, 158L, 159L, 160L, 161L, 162L, 163L, 164L, 165L, 166L, 167L, 
168L, 169L, 170L, 171L, 172L, 173L, 174L, 175L, 176L, 177L, 178L, 
179L, 180L, 181L, 182L, 183L, 184L, 185L, 186L, 187L, 188L, 189L, 
190L, 191L, 192L, 193L, 194L, 195L, 196L, 197L, 198L, 199L, 200L, 
201L, 202L, 203L, 204L, 205L, 206L, 207L, 208L, 209L, 210L, 211L, 
212L, 213L, 214L, 215L, 216L, 217L, 218L, 219L, 220L, 221L, 222L, 
223L, 224L, 225L, 226L, 227L, 228L, 229L, 230L, 231L, 232L, 233L, 
234L, 235L, 236L, 237L, 238L, 239L, 240L, 241L, 242L, 243L, 244L, 
245L, 246L, 247L, 248L, 249L, 250L, 251L, 252L, 253L, 254L, 255L, 
256L, 257L, 258L, 259L, 260L, 261L, 262L, 263L, 264L, 265L, 266L, 
267L, 268L, 269L, 270L, 271L, 272L, 273L, 274L, 275L, 276L, 277L, 
278L, 279L, 280L, 281L, 282L, 283L, 284L, 285L, 286L, 287L, 288L, 
289L, 290L, 291L, 292L, 293L, 294L, 295L, 296L, 297L, 298L, 299L, 
300L, 301L, 302L, 303L, 304L, 305L, 306L, 307L, 308L, 309L, 310L, 
311L, 312L, 313L, 314L, 315L, 316L, 317L, 318L, 319L, 320L, 321L, 
322L, 323L, 324L, 325L, 326L, 327L, 328L, 329L, 330L, 331L, 332L, 
333L, 334L, 335L, 336L, 337L, 338L, 339L, 340L, 341L, 342L, 343L, 
344L, 345L, 346L, 347L, 348L, 349L, 350L, 351L, 352L, 353L, 354L, 
355L, 356L, 357L, 358L, 359L, 360L, 361L, 362L, 363L, 364L, 365L, 
366L, 367L, 368L, 369L, 370L, 371L, 372L, 373L, 374L, 375L, 376L, 
377L, 378L, 379L, 380L, 381L, 382L, 383L, 384L, 385L, 386L, 387L, 
388L, 389L, 390L, 391L, 392L, 393L, 394L, 395L, 396L, 397L, 398L, 
399L, 400L, 401L, 402L, 403L, 404L, 405L, 406L, 407L, 408L, 409L, 
410L, 411L, 412L, 413L, 414L, 415L, 416L, 417L, 418L, 419L, 420L, 
421L, 422L, 423L, 424L, 425L, 426L, 427L, 428L, 429L, 430L, 431L, 
432L, 433L, 434L, 435L, 436L, 437L, 438L, 439L, 440L, 441L, 442L, 
443L, 444L, 445L, 446L, 447L, 448L, 449L, 450L, 451L, 452L, 453L, 
454L, 455L, 456L, 457L, 458L, 459L, 460L, 461L, 462L, 463L, 464L, 
465L, 466L, 467L, 468L, 469L, 470L, 471L, 472L, 473L, 474L, 475L, 
476L, 477L, 478L, 479L, 480L, 481L, 482L, 483L, 484L, 485L, 486L, 
487L, 488L, 489L, 490L, 491L, 492L, 493L, 494L, 495L, 496L, 497L, 
498L, 499L, 500L, 501L, 502L, 503L, 504L, 505L, 506L, 507L, 508L, 
509L, 510L, 511L, 512L, 513L, 514L, 515L, 516L, 517L, 518L, 519L, 
520L, 521L, 522L, 523L, 524L, 525L, 526L, 527L, 528L, 529L, 530L, 
531L, 532L, 533L, 534L, 535L, 536L, 537L, 538L, 539L, 540L, 541L, 
542L, 543L, 544L, 545L, 546L, 547L, 548L, 549L, 550L, 551L, 552L, 
553L, 554L, 555L, 556L, 557L, 558L, 559L, 560L, 561L, 562L, 563L, 
564L, 565L, 566L, 567L, 568L, 569L, 570L, 571L, 572L, 573L, 574L, 
575L, 576L, 577L, 578L, 579L, 580L, 581L, 582L, 583L, 584L, 585L, 
586L, 587L, 588L, 589L, 590L, 591L, 592L, 593L, 594L, 595L, 596L, 
597L, 598L, 599L, 600L, 601L, 602L, 603L, 604L, 605L, 606L, 607L, 
608L, 609L, 610L, 611L, 612L, 613L, 614L, 615L, 616L, 617L, 618L, 
619L, 620L, 621L, 622L, 623L, 624L, 625L, 626L, 627L, 628L, 629L, 
630L, 631L, 632L, 633L, 634L, 635L, 636L, 637L, 638L, 639L, 640L, 
641L, 642L, 643L, 644L, 645L, 646L, 647L, 648L, 649L, 650L, 651L, 
652L, 653L, 654L, 655L, 656L, 657L, 658L, 659L, 660L, 661L, 662L, 
663L, 664L, 665L, 666L, 667L, 668L, 669L, 670L, 671L, 672L, 673L, 
674L, 675L, 676L, 677L, 678L, 679L, 680L, 681L, 682L, 683L, 684L, 
685L, 686L, 687L, 688L, 689L, 690L, 691L, 692L, 693L, 694L, 695L, 
696L, 697L, 698L, 699L, 700L, 701L, 702L, 703L, 704L, 705L, 706L, 
707L, 708L, 709L, 710L, 711L, 712L, 713L, 714L, 715L, 716L, 717L, 
718L, 719L, 720L, 721L, 722L, 723L, 724L, 725L, 726L, 727L, 728L, 
729L, 730L, 731L, 732L, 733L, 734L, 735L, 736L, 737L, 738L, 739L, 
740L, 741L, 742L, 743L, 744L, 745L, 746L, 747L, 748L, 749L, 750L, 
751L, 752L, 753L, 754L, 755L, 756L, 757L, 758L, 759L, 760L, 761L, 
762L, 763L, 764L, 765L, 766L, 767L, 768L, 769L, 770L, 771L, 772L, 
773L, 774L, 775L, 776L, 777L, 778L, 779L, 780L, 781L, 782L, 783L, 
784L, 785L, 786L, 787L, 788L, 789L, 790L, 791L, 792L, 793L, 794L, 
795L, 796L, 797L, 798L, 799L, 800L, 801L, 802L, 803L, 804L, 805L, 
806L, 807L, 808L, 809L, 810L, 811L, 812L, 813L, 814L, 815L, 816L, 
817L, 818L, 819L, 820L, 821L, 822L, 823L, 824L, 825L, 826L, 827L, 
828L, 829L, 830L, 831L, 832L, 833L, 834L, 835L, 836L, 837L, 838L, 
839L, 840L, 841L, 842L, 843L, 844L, 845L, 846L, 847L, 848L, 849L, 
850L, 851L, 852L, 853L, 854L, 855L, 856L, 857L, 858L, 859L, 860L, 
861L, 862L, 863L, 864L, 865L, 866L, 867L, 868L, 869L, 870L, 871L, 
872L, 873L, 874L, 875L, 876L, 877L, 878L, 879L, 880L, 881L, 882L, 
883L, 884L, 885L, 886L, 887L, 888L, 889L, 890L, 891L, 892L, 893L, 
894L, 895L, 896L, 897L, 898L, 899L, 900L, 901L, 902L, 903L, 904L, 
905L, 906L, 907L, 908L, 909L, 910L, 911L, 912L, 913L, 914L, 915L, 
916L, 917L, 918L), Year = c(2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 
2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 
2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 
2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 
2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 
2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 
2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 
2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 
2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 
2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 
2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 
2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 
2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 
2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 
2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 
2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 
2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 
2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 
2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 
2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 
2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 
2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 
2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 
2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 
2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 
2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 
2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 
2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 
2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 
2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 
2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 
2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 
2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 
2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 
2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 
2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 
2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 
2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 
2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 
2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 
2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 
2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 
2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 
2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 
2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 
2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 
2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 
2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 
2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 
2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 
2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 
2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 
2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 
2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 
2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 
2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 
2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 
2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 
2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 
2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 
2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 
2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 
2016L, 2016L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
2017L, 2017L, 2017L), Month = structure(c(5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
9L, 9L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
11L, 11L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
9L, 9L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
9L, 9L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("April", "August", 
"December", "February", "January", "July", "March", "May", "November", 
"October", "September"), class = "factor"), year = c(2015L, 2015L, 
2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 
2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 
2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 
2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 
2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 
2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 
2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 
2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 
2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 
2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 
2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 
2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 
2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 
2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 
2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 
2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 
2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 
2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 
2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 
2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 
2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 
2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 
2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 
2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 
2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 
2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 
2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 
2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 
2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 
2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 
2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 
2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 
2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 
2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 
2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 
2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 
2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 
2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 
2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 
2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 
2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 
2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 
2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 
2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 
2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 
2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 
2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 
2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 
2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 
2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 
2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 
2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 
2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 
2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 
2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 
2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 
2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 
2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 
2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 
2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 
2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 
2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L)), row.names = c(NA, 
-917L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: so.. all you need is the average FID by year-month? If so: `library(data.table);setDT(mydata)[, .(mean = mean(FID)), by = .(year, Month)]` will do the trick

Comment: your column `FID$Month` is a `factor` right now and the error message say it has to be `numeric`, so `dat$Month <- as.numeric(dat$Month)` should fix that error.

Comment: Also it asks for the column to be call `month` not `Month` so that needs to be tweaked too

Comment: Hey Nate. Thank you for your advice. I restructured the data frame and renamed the column Month to month. 
New_Blue_Edited_Final$FID<-as.numeric(New_Blue_Edited_Final$FID)
New_Blue_Edited_Final$month <- as.numeric(New_Blue_Edited_Final$month)
New_Blue_Edited_Final$Year<-as.numeric(New_Blue_Edited_Final$Year)
New_Blue_Edited_Final$year<-as.numeric(New_Blue_Edited_Final$year)

Comment: I ran the model and I got this error message: Total number of days =  1096 
 Show Traceback
 
 Rerun with Debug
 Error in `[.data.frame`(x, r, vars, drop = drop) : 
  undefined columns selected

Comment: Called from: `[.data.frame`(x, r, vars, drop = drop)
Error during wrapup: unimplemented type (29) in 'eval'

Error: no more error handlers available (recursive errors?); invoking 'abort' restart
Error during wrapup: INTEGER() can only be applied to a 'integer', not a 'unknown type #29'
Error: no more error handlers available (recursive errors?); invoking 'abort' restart